# In C, what is the difference between the two given code snippets relating to malloc and variable array declaration?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Do the below codes do the exact same thing?

Code Snippet 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int arr[size];
    //code to manipulate array
    return 0;
}
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int *arr = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    //code to manipulate array
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The storage for the array is different (stack vs heap in most implementations; in the terms of the C standard, automatic vs allocated storage), but the code represented by the comment can be the same unless it uses features such as `sizeof(arr)`.

Comment: What would that difference be, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not the same.

The first snippet creates an array with automatic storage duration, i.e. on the stack in most implementations, while the second creates an array dynamically on the heap.  The former has a lifetime of the scope than encloses it, while the latter is valid for the lifetime of the program or until it is freed, whichever comes first.